# Finding power source for sensor with no power source in proteus

Tags: embedded, simulation

So I want to simulate attaching a soil moisture sensor to an Arduino Uno Board and reading the values on a terminal in Proteus Design Suite but the component for the Arduino board am using has the VCC and GND pins hidden. First of all, what does that mean and how to I find power source for both the board and the sensor.

Comment: This is the wrong place for such a question.  Try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/